# Interactive Data table visual power bi via R/python

Tags: python, html, r, powerbi

I am attempting to display a table in powerbi that includes a ' checkbox' field that the user can tick or untick.

So far, the closest I've come is to create such a table in R using the *rhandsontable* library.

'''

```
DF = data.frame(integer = 
1:10,
               numeric = 
rnorm(10),
               logical = 
rep(TRUE, 10), 
               character = 
LETTERS[1:10],
               factor = 
factor(letters[1:10], levels = 
letters[10:1], 
                               
ordered = TRUE),
               factor_allow = 
factor(letters[1:10], levels = 
letters[10:1], 
                                     
ordered = TRUE),
               date = seq(from 
= Sys.Date(), by = "days", 
length.out = 10),
               
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(DF, width = 600, 
height = 300) %>%
  hot_col("factor_allow", 
allowInvalid = TRUE)
```

'''

This solution works in R . However,  in powerBi ( through the R script visual), it gets the following error: " cannot display visual".

From what I can tell, this is because Powerbi cannot display dynamic html visuals.  If this correct, is there a way around this or alternate solution?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to use pbiviz, because rhandsontable returns a htmlwidget. Search in my posts for a link.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Does it still work for DB connections or is it only for when the data is a flat file ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unless I'm mistaken, the link on your profile thst you are referring to is for interactive graphs and doesn't extend to interactive tables?

Comment: That works for any htmlwidget.